# How to find the value "-32767" in 450 columns in a BigQuery table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table with 450 columns and millions of rows. As can be expected, the table has columns of all types like datetime, date, integer, numeric and string. I want to know which column contains the value "-32767". Is there a way to accomplish this in **BigQuery**?

Answer (score 1):

Consider below

```
create temp function  extract_keys(input string) returns array<string> language js as """
  return Object.keys(JSON.parse(input));
  """;
create temp function  extract_values(input string) returns array<string> language js as """
  return Object.values(JSON.parse(input));
  """;
select col, count(*) cnt
from your_table t,
unnest([struct(to_json_string(t) as json)]),
unnest(extract_keys(json)) col with offset
join unnest(extract_values(json)) val with offset
using(offset)
where val = '-32767'
group by col
```

this will give you output like below

[image]

Where col3, col2 are columns that have `-32767` value and 4,1 is how many rows involved respectively

> How can I modify it and give it a subset of columns where I expect the value can be?

Assuming you want to limit "search" to only `col1` and `col3` - use below

```
select col, count(*) cnt
from your_table t,
unnest([struct(to_json_string((select as struct col1, col3 from unnest([t]))) as json)]),
unnest(extract_keys(json)) col with offset
join unnest(extract_values(json)) val with offset
using(offset)
where val = '-32767'
group by col
```

Comment: Thanks you for sharing this. It's been running for 10 minutes now. How can I modify it and give it a subset of columns where I expect the value can be?